# Playing Minecraft with a controller, except the controls are all wrong

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc, controllers

So, I just got a PC X-Box controller, I downloaded JoyToKey and a config file for Minecraft, but when I move the stick to the left, it goes up. When I move it down, it goes right etc. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Welcome to the Arqade! You are allowed to self-answer your own questions, and it's absolutely preferred to editing your question the way you have.

Comment: @Erik - I have removed your answer from your question, and added it as a community wiki answer for the time being. If you wish to mark it as accepted, or to add an answer of your own, please do so.

Answer (score 1):

The OP's answer originally posted in the question body:

---

I fixed it, It was the wrong joystick number.